# Как написать интроспективную программу

Tags: c++, вывод

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать интроспективную программу на с++. Интроспективная программа-это программа, которая, будучи запущенной, выводит саму себя. При этом нельзя пользоваться файлами с кодом и/или системно-зависимыми вещами вроде адресов памяти и прочего.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/126075/

Comment: Или, более теоретически, https://habr.com/ru/post/128191/